# Remove characters from a cell

Tags: excel, vba

This formula removes everything except numbers:

```
Sub qwerty()
    For Each r In Selection
        vout = ""
        v = r.Text
        n = Len(v)
        For i = 1 To n
            ch = Mid(v, i, 1)
            If ch Like "[0-9]" Then
                vout = vout & ch
            End If
        Next i
        r.Value = vout
    Next r
End Sub
```

How can I modify it so that it will keep numbers and decimal points?

Comment: This was literally answered just a few minutes ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487287/script-to-remove-letters)

Comment: Scott - I tried the one you linked, but for some reason the macro isn't visible to me from the excel sheet. The one I posted is visible. Basically, the one you linked does not work for me, but this one does. I just need to retain decimal points in addition to numbers and would like to stick with this code because it is simple.

Comment: What does visibility mean???? Have you tried `or`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include `.`, include it in your `Like` expression

```
If ch Like "[0-9.]" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use a `Regexp` than slowly loop character by character through an inital range loop:

```
Sub Quicker()
Dim X
Dim ObjRegex As Object
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCOl As Long

Set ObjRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
ObjRegex.Global = True
ObjRegex.Pattern = "[^0-9/.]"

X = Selection.Value2
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
   For lngCOl = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
        X(lngRow, lngCOl) = ObjRegex.Replace(X(lngRow, lngCOl), vbNullString)
   Next
Next

Selection.Value2 = X

End Sub
```